# Find part of <img> source and remove - end

Tags: jquery, regex

I have this image source:

```
domain.com/wp-content/themes/directorypress/thumbs/CambridgeSlide_harvardsquare.jpg&w=695
```

I would like to try and remove "&w=695" - what is the best way to do this? Find it with regex and then remove it and update the image source?

Been trying some methods and nothing seems to be working.

Thanks,

Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even simpler than that! Simply split the string by the & and you have your answer!

```
var str = "domain.com/wp-content/themes/directorypress/thumbs/CambridgeSlide_harvardsquare.jpg&w=695";
arr = str.split("&");
return arr[0];
```

​

http://jsfiddle.net/9KhwX/1/

Answer (score 1):

No need to use a regular expression, `lastIndexOf` and `substring` is all you need:

```
var $img = $("img"),
    imgSrc = $img.attr('src'),
    newImgSrc = imgSrc.substring(0, imgSrc.lastIndexOf('&'));
$img.attr('src', newImgSrc);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img').prop('src', function(i, value) {
    return value.replace(/\&.+$/, '');
});

alert($('img').prop('src'));
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/uqHjt/1/)